# Can I have a comma followed by a word at the end of a sentence?

Tags: commas, sentence-ends

Consider:

> During this time of self-reflection, King was introduced to the teachings of a man who fought on the other side of the world, Gandhi.

Is it legal to include a comma between "world" and Gandhi". I know that a colon is much better, but I want to know if a comma is also perfectly legal. And if it is, may I ask why?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no laws against using comma's - but I'm not a lawyer, and in your country there may be such laws - who knows. As far as English is concerned, to me that comma seems just fine.

Comment: Thank you. What if I included a prepositional phrase and non-restrictive clause (two commas) after the world ", for the rights of the oppressed,"?

During this time of self-reflection, King was introduced to the teachings of a man who fought on the other side of the world, for the rights of the oppressed, Gandhi?

Comment: I still see no problems, except the sentence is starting to get a bit long :)

Comment: @oerkelens Does having a comma before Gandhi make the word "Gandhi" a non-restrictive clause?

Comment: I'm still of the opinion that the comma after "world" should be a colon.

During this time of self-reflection, King was introduced to the teachings of a man who fought on the other side of the world, Gandhi.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd prefer a colon in the example given, but I have no issue with the comma either. Both work in my eyes; it's just a stylistic thing mainly.

Comment: It would probably also be better to give him his full name, but that's nothing to do with the legitimacy of the comma